# In Android, How to monitor other app's sqlite database and update some rows

Tags: android

I want to implement an Android app which can monitor another specific app's sqlite database, and remove some specific rows from a table. The working senaria is as below:

1. Open a specific social app (for example, twitter), and press
   Refresh/LoadMore
2. The social app sends HTTP request to retrieve
   data
3. The social app parses the result, and insert into sqlite
   database
4. [My App] My app monitors the table changes, and update
   some rows
5. The social app displays records from sqlite to UI (The
   rows that my app removes will not be displayed in UI).

Is it possible to develop such kind of app? I understand this app needs root access. But if the app has root access, can I achieve this goal? Thanks.

Comment: Ouch! I would hate another app messing up with my app's data. ;-) Have you considered how it would affect the target app, if your app was to corrupt the data in it?

Comment: This is functionality that should be exposed by the app in question, not something you forcefully take.

Comment: thanks for comment. here i just want to know whether it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

this is only done when other app have used `ContentProvider` and the give us Permission for access that.

A `ContentProvider` can be used internally in an application to access data. If the data should be shared with another application a ContentProvider allows this.

Many Android datasources, e.g. the `contacts`, are accessible via `ContentProviders`. `Typically the implementing classes for a ContentProviders provide public constants for the URIs.`

for more detail check this [artical](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) and this two artical from Adnroid Developer [one](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and [two](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)

Comment: Thanks. If the target app's content provider's provider is "android:exported=false", then even if my app has root access, it still cannot access it?

Comment: i am not saggest you to do this but you can access all file system if your app have root access.

Comment: yes, I can do that. But I really like the observer design pattern, and do not want to do loop check. That's why I want to know whether I can access other app's ContentProviders even if it's set to exported= false.